# Skip duplicates on field in a Elasticsearch search result

Tags: elasticsearch, search, duplicates, nosql

Is it possible to remove duplicates on a given field?

For example the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name_admin": {
        "value": "nike"
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "name_admin",
    "parent_sku",
    "sku"
  ],
  "size": 2
}
```

is retrieving

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "product",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "central30603",
        "_score" : 4.596813,
        "_source" : {
          "parent_sku" : "SSP57",
          "sku" : "SSP57816401",
          "name_admin" : "NIKE U NSW PRO CAP NIKE AIR"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "product",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "central156578",
        "_score" : 4.596813,
        "_source" : {
          "parent_sku" : "SSP57",
          "sku" : "SSP57816395",
          "name_admin" : "NIKE U NSW PRO CAP NIKE AIR"
        }
      }
    ]
```

I'd like to skip duplicates on `parent_sku` so I only have one result per `parent_sku` like it's possible with `suggestion` by doing something like `"skip_duplicates": true`.

I know I cloud achieve this with an `aggregation` but I'd like to stick with a search, as my query is a bit more complicated and as I'm using the `scroll` API which doesn't work with aggregations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-collapse) should help here

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name_admin": {
        "value": "nike"
      }
    }
  },
  "collapse" : {
      "field" : "parent_sku",
      "inner_hits": {
          "name": "parent", 
          "size": 1
      }
  },
  "_source": false,
  "size": 2
}
```

The above query will return one document par `parent_sku`.