# Retrieve distinct values for search as you type in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a field `title` and the type is `search_as_you_type`,

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and when we a searching

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "title": "red"
    }
  }
}
```

we are getting duplicates results

```
red car
red icecream
red car
```

This is because we have documents with same title values.

Is there a way to indicate that result must have distinct vaules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see terms aggregation of your `title` field in case of search as you type works on not by following the example given in [this SO answer] [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28189989/4039431). You can also check [this blog](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-get-unique-values-for-a-field-in-elasticsearch) which explains how to get unique values from Elasticsearch.

Also, make sure these documents which are coming in your results are the same documents and not the different document which has the same values.

**Edit:- As discussed in the comment, in this case, [completion suggestor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-suggesters-completion.html) was more useful as it deals with duplicates and it solved the issue.**

Comment: Yes, we have same title for different documents

Comment: then they are essentially different docs and you want to filter them correct? also did you get a chance to go through the links I provided and lmk if it helps

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve just one of them, without duplicates, and I can not use aggregation by terms as the field's type is `search_as_you_type` and I can not add `"fielddata": true`, have you tried your solution?

Comment: @user13674325 nope I dont have much exp with search as you type datatype hence didn't try it, but by looking at your comments it seems the culprit(and its quite likely link I mentioned wont work), did you consider prefix query or match phrase prefix query for your feature ?

Comment: You should create another `keyword` sub-field on the title field so you could leverage field collapsing. This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152287/skip-duplicates-on-field-in-a-elasticsearch-search-result/62152464#62152464

Comment: @user13674325 But you would probably be better off using the [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#skip_duplicates) which deals with duplicates

Comment: @Val ohh yeah thats even better +1

Comment: @user13674325 any luck here ?

Comment: yes, I decided to go with completion suggester, and it works